# Copy Specific Column Values to another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a time and motion study tracker with start, end and submit button button. I managed to worked on start and end.

But I am struggling to copy an specific data to my masterfile. In my workbook, I have a dropdown selection of status.. If the value of the dropdown is" Pending", then those cases should be submitted in my Archive workbook Sheet1 when I hit the Submit button and the status in my last column will be updated to Submitted. So it will exclude those cases on my next submission and should not overlap the data in master file.

Kinda lost with the If statement.

Hoping to solve this problem with the help from you guys.

```
Sub Submit()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prod")


Dim Outapp As Object, Logfile As String

lr As Long, Archive As Workbook


sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prod")

Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim r As Long, lr As Long, Archive As Workbook

r = 2
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Archive = Workbook.Open("C:\Users\ChrisLacs\Desktop\Test\Archive.xlsm")

Do Until r = lr + 2


lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(sh.Range("D:D"))

For x = 2 To lastrow

If sh.Range("O" & i).Value <> "Submitted" And sh.Range("J" & i).Value = "Pending" Then

Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 3)).Copy

Archive.Worksheets("Prod").Select
erow = Archive.Worksheets("Prod").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Archive.Worksheets("Prod").Rows(erow)

Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 4)).Value = ""

End If

r = r + 1

Looop



Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the aim of the Dir() loop?  If it locates "Archive.xlsm" it just exits the Sub: it's not clear why.  What is `wsPaste` for?

Comment: Im not sure if Loop is necessary..  I just wanted to copy the column J, column A and B. if  the Value of O is = Submitted..

Comment: Copy to where?  "Archive.xlsm"?  You don't need Dir() if you already know where the file is and what its name is...

Comment: I have updated my codes. Im not sure if Loop is necessary for this case. After copying from the source file. It should paste on another workbook Sheet1. And so on.. to the next available cell if I choose to submit another data

Comment: Would you be kind, to amend my codes in to proper way? Im kinda new to this VBA thing  but it requires me aty this moment.. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub Submit()
    Const WB_ARCH_PATH As String = "C:\Users\ChrisLacs\Desktop\Test\"
    Const WB_ARCH_NM As String = "Archive.xlsm """
    
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, r As Long, rw As Range, wbArch As Workbook
    Dim wsArch As Worksheet, cDest As Range
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prod")  'source data sheet
    'open archive workbook if not already open
    On Error Resume Next                     'ignore error if not open
    Set wbArch = Workbooks(WB_ARCH_NM)
    On Error GoTo 0                          'stop ignoring errors
    If wbArch Is Nothing Then Set wbArch = Workbooks.Open(WB_ARCH_PATH & WB_ARCH_NM)
    Set wsArch = wbArch.Worksheets("Prod")
    Set cDest = wsArch.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'first paste destination
    
    For r = 2 To wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'loop source rows
        Set rw = wsSrc.Rows(r)
        If rw.Columns("O").Value <> "Submitted" And rw.Columns("J").Value = "Pending" Then
            rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 3).Copy cDest  'Copy A:C for row `rw`
            rw.Columns("O").Value = "Submitted"  'update to Submitted
            Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0)       'next paste destination
        End If
    Next r
    
    wbArch.Close True 'save changes
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Okay i was having an error earlier with line    Const WB_ARCH_NM As String = "Archive.xlsm """   and managed to fixed the issue. However, Im having an error with this line.   Set wsArch = wbArch.Worksheets("Prod"). =(

Comment: "an error" is not a great description of what happens when you run the code: please provide more details so I can try to help resolve the problem.

Comment: Sorry should be `Dim wsArch As Worksheet`.  Fixed above.

Comment: `For r = 2 To wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` there's nothing in Col A in your source worksheet: change that to a column which will always have content for any given row.

Comment: Oh My.. That works! Awesome! I cant Thank you enough =)

Comment: I just noticed. in my next submission. it overlaps the masterfile. The data should be continuos and should be paste in the next available cell in my archive workbook. Am I missing something?

Comment: You may need to adjust this line: `Set cDest = wsArch.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` I wrote that assuming you'd have content in ColA, so you need to account for the fact your file has nothing in ColA...   Maybe `rw.Cells(2).Resize(1, 3).Copy cDest` if you want to start the copy from Col B.